# Injecting data into Phoenix's Action params

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to write some plugs to reduce amount of unneeded code in project and I would love to take some session data and put it into _params in controller's actions. But I have no idea how to do it. I came across the functon assign/3 but as far as i know it assigns data to be used in templates.

```
def logged(conn, _opts) do
    case get_session(conn, :login) do
      nil -> conn
        |> Phoenix.Controller.put_flash(:error, "Musisz być zalogowany")
        |> Phoenix.Controller.redirect( to: "/")
        |> Plug.Conn.halt
      login -> #here
    end
  end
```

And i want to be able to do:

```
def someaction(conn, %{"login" => login}) do
  #do something with login
end
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two places where you can store key value pairs on a `Plug.Conn` struct. [assigns](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#assign/3) and [private](http://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#put_private/3). Generally you should use `assigns` for your application and `private` for libraries.

> This storage is meant to be used by libraries and frameworks to avoid writing to the user storage (the :assigns field). It is recommended for libraries/frameworks to prefix the keys with the library name.

Using `assign` got your user:

```
def logged(conn, _opts) do
    case get_session(conn, :login) do
      nil -> conn
        ...
      login -> Plug.Conn.assign(conn, :current_user, login)
    end
  end

def someaction(conn, _params) do
  # do something with conn.assigns.current_user
end
```

If you use the `current_user` in your controller functions frequently then consider overriding the `action/2` function in your controller. As documented in "Overriding `action/2` for custom arguments" in [the docs](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#summary)

```
def action(conn, _params) do
  apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn), [conn, conn.params, conn.assigns.current_user)
end

def someaction(conn, _params, current_user) do
  # do something with current_user
end
```

For completeness. You can update the params (I wouldn't in the case of user authentication) using [Kernel.update_in/2](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/v1.1/elixir/Kernel.html#update_in/2) as `conn.params` is a map:

```
update_in(conn.params, fn (params) -> Map.put(params, :something, "value") end)
```